# ScrollTo conflict with Mousewheel.js, need more specific events?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, scrollto, side-scroller

I'm building a side scrolling website. I'm using Mousewheel.js from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/) to enable sidescrolling and scrollTo from [Ariel Flesler](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) to jump to specific points in the site (which I haven't really mastered yet but I think that's besides the point). When I try to utilize them together I get this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mousewheel'
```

Mousewheel utilizes this script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#container").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
    $(".post").wrap("<td></td>");
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
        event.preventDefault();
    });   
});
```

I suspect that the event is not specific enough but I'm not sure how to fix that. In case it wasn't already obvious from my question, I'm a jQuery noob.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance we take a look at the page you're working on? Is it possible to publish it?

Comment: Sure, edited the OP with link to rough page.

Comment: did you place mousewheel.js after your jquery.js?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had not included a copy of scrollTo that was visible to the html page.